# Matching @user with regex

Tags: python, regex, twitter

How do I match words that begin with `@` and ends with `;`, `.`, `:`, or   ?

The words can have any alphanumeric characters and may consist of underscores.

I have come up with `^@([a-zA-Z0-9_])*[:;, ]$` which seems to work for single word sentences alone.

Comment: Since this is Twitter we're talking about, you'll probably want to restrict this to 15 characters (username max length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` matches the start of a string (or line, in multi-line mode), while `$` matches the end, so you need to get rid of them:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = "foo bar @match don't match @success;"
>>> re.findall('@([a-zA-Z0-9_])*[:;, ]', sentence)
['h', 's']
```

It is only capturing the last letter because the qualifier (the `*`) is outside the brackets matching the capture. Move it inside and you get:

```
>>> re.findall('@([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[:;, ]', sentence)
['match', 'success']
```

If you want to capture the @ and trailing character too, just move them inside the brackets as well:

```
>>> re.findall('(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[:;, ])', sentence)
['@match ', '@success;']
```

And as mentioned in the comments on the question, you may or may not want to restrict it to a certain number of characters:

```
>>> sentence = "foo bar @match don't match @somereallylongnamehere @success;"
>>> re.findall('(@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}[:;, ])', sentence)
['@match ', '@success;']
```

(Of course, the length restriction could be added to any of the previous expressions, not just this last one).

Comment: Ah! now i get it i put * outside the capturing group. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the anchor `^` and `$` and you will be good to go.

In case you don't want to match empty string from `"Example @ nothing"`, you may want to specify "1 or more qualifier" `+` instead of `*`. i.e. `@([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[:;, ]`

Restricting to 1-15 character username can be done by replacing `*` with `{1,15}`, i.e. `@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})[:;, ]`.

If you want to get @ sign plus the ending characters as result, `@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}[:;, ]` is sufficient.

If you want to capture the name only, you can use this `@([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15})[:;, ]`

In case the token is right at the end of the string and without the special characters, and you want to capture it, you may want to modify `[:;, ]` to `(?:[:;, ]|$)`